# Can literal angle brackets be used in quoted XML attribute value strings?

Tags: xml, escaping

For example, is this valid XML?:

```
<foo bar="3<5" />
```

Or do I *have* to escape them?:

```
<foo bar="3&lt;5" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the literal <.

You can check this using any XML Validator.

Comment: Is there a reason for that, even though it is in quotation marks?

Comment: Regardless of whether it is inside the quotes or not, it is still a character with special meaning for the XML Parser.